# list finding with 2 list

Tags: c#, list

in my program i have 2 list :

```
List<string> aaa = new List<string>();
List<string> bbb = new List<string>();
```

in list aaa i have numbers like (1 2 3 4).
in list bbb i have numbers like (0 1 0 1).

now i need to check if an index is not empty on list aaa.
after thath i need to get value of index(if not empty).
then retrive value on bbb at same aaa.index.

i use:

```
var exist = aaa.Find(x => x == "2");
```

but some clarification needed.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What clarification is needed? Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: What is your question?  Your query seems to be different from what you have explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var inx = aaa.IndexOf("2");
if (inx >= 0)
{
    var result = bbb[inx];
}
```